# How to link cpp and h files together?

Tags: c++

**SOLVED**

```
// Solution:
// foo.c includes foo.h; bar.c includes bar.h
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -o foobar foo.cpp bar.cpp
```

I have two cpp files and two h files. I have the first cpp linked to h file of the same name which is linked to the second cpp file that's linked to the second h file. Is this the way I should link the files together?

My program is not working. There are errors too, but I need to make sure if this is part of the error. Is this the way to define/link cpp and h files?

```
 // file: foo.cpp
 #include "foo.h"

 // file: foo.h
 #include "bar.cpp"

 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iostream>
 using std::cin;
 using std::cout;
 using std::cerr;
 using std::stringstream;
 using std::string;
 using std::endl;

 // file: bar.cpp
 #include "bar.h"

 // file: bar.h
 // ...
```

Comment: This looks just blatantly wrong: `#include "bar.cpp"` Usually you never include `.cpp` files. Compile every `.cpp` file to `.o` or `.obj` and call the linker to create an executable from all of these object files.

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://david.rothlis.net/c/compilation_model/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completely wrong. Header files are to be included in cpp files. Cpp files are never included in anything. Typically, header files hold declarations, and cpp files hold definitions.

If your program consists of two cpp files, you do not include one in the other. Instead, you compile them together into a single executable.

I would guess that you have some misconceptions about the way declarations and definitions work, or what including does. I suggest you brush up with a textbook, or take a look at some small C++ programs on github.

Answer (score 1):

No. You shouldn't `#include` cpp files. Also, you're using the term 'link' incorrectly.

- cpp files should #include their corresponding header file, if they have one, on their first line: bar.cpp should #include bar.h, foo.cpp should #include foo.h.
- every header should be #included as the first header in a corresponding cpp file, even if you have to make an empty corresponding cpp file just to #include the header.
- header files should #include only other headers
- cpp files should #include headers for other interfaces they use, or should include forward declarations, if you can write valid forward declarations.

'Linking' has nothing to do with `#include`. It's the task performed by the linker after compilation/assembly has been performed. Linking is performed on object files and libraries, not headers or cpp files.